# MySQL Selecting Rows and Grouping

Tags: mysql, database, join, subquery, grouping

I have a ( Joomla) database table called `field_values`, the contents are below;

```
+----+----------+---------+---------+
| id | field_id | item_id | value   |
+----+----------+---------+---------+
| 1  | 2        | 446     | Jones   |
| 2  | 2        | 447     | Smith   |
| 3  | 2        | 448     | Jenkins |
| 4  | 3        | 446     | Paul    |
| 5  | 3        | 447     | Peter   |
| 6  | 3        | 448     | Sally   |
| 7  | 4        | 446     | London  |
| 8  | 4        | 447     | Dublin  |
| 9  | 4        | 448     | Paris   |
+----+----------+---------+---------+
```

I'm only displaying 9 rows from the table, but I actually have thousands, so the successful query would need to take this into account.

Columns explained;

- id (primary / auto-increment)
- field_id (FK to another `fields` table, `2` = surname, `3` = first name, `4` = location)
- item_id (FK to another `users` table)
- value (contents of field)

How can I select all the values from the above table but display them as follows;

```
+------------+-----------+----------+
| first_name | last_name | location |
+------------+-----------+----------+
| Paul       | Jones     | London   |
| Peter      | Smith     | Dublin   |
| Sally      | Jenkins   | Paris    |
+------------+-----------+----------+
```

The `id` field isn't really necessary in the desired results above, I just added it to emphasise that each row is unique.

I'm not sure if I need to use a subquery or group by, maybe neither?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't really understand the meaning of `id` in the result set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pivot query should work here:

```
SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN field_id = 3 THEN value END) AS first_name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN field_id = 2 THEN value END) AS last_name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN field_id = 4 THEN value END) AS location
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    item_id
ORDER BY 
    item_id;
```

Your current table structure is a denormalized key value store, a style which WordPress uses in some of its tables.

Comment: Do you mean to say that you expect thousands of _columns_ in your pivoted output?  What I wrote above is the best you can do without resorting to dynamic SQL, e.g. in a stored procedure.

Comment: @TheOrdinaryGeek If you have thousands of different entities (item_ids), the above will work just fine. For thousands of different attributes (field_ids), consider managing that in application code instead. Anyway, now you know the terms to google for!

Comment: OK...do you have thousands of users, thousands of properties, or both?

Answer (score 0):

you could avoid  subquery and grou by. 
You could use the same table 3 times

```
select  a.id, b.value firts_name, a.value last_name , c.value location
from  field_values a 
inner join  field_values b  on a.item_id = b.item_id and b.field_id = 3 
inner join  field_values bc on a.item_id = c.item_id and b.field_id = 4
where a.item_id = 2
```